# how to drop the second curly bracket?

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to modify the following List:

```
vtable ={ { {0,{0}},{0, {1}}} ,{{1,{0}},{1,{1}}}  }
```

as follows:

```
vtable={{0,0},{0,1},{1,0},{1,1}}
```

that is I want to remove the far most internal bracket of the list....

I read about the Flatten command but I cannot do much...actually what I get is something like
{{0,{0}},{0,{1}}, ....} or even worse...
{0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1}

How  can I do that? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try with:

```
Flatten /@ Flatten[vtable, 1]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

Answer (score 14):

```
Flatten /@ (Join @@ vtable)
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

```
ArrayReshape[vtable, {4, 2}]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

```
Join @@ vtable /. {a_} :> a
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

```
MapAt[Sequence @@ # &, vtable, {{All, All, -1}, {1}, {2}}]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

Comment: Thanks for your professional answer but it is for the time being a bit too advanced for me...(+10)

Answer (score 7):

```
 vtable /. {x_, {y_}} :> {x, y} // Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

Comment: (+1) `vtable /. {x_, {y_}} :> {x, y} // Catenate`  is a (very) slight variant

Answer (score 6):

```
Replace[Catenate[vtable], {x_,{y_}}:> {x,y},{1}]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}

Answer (score 5):

```
Partition[Flatten[vtable],2]
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}}